# Unable to access a service inside my minikube cluster

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-service

I set up a single node cluster using minikube. I have also configured a client pod inside this node and also a nodeport service to access the pod. But the service is unreachable on browser.

Below are the config files for client pod and the nodeport service:

**client-pod.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: client-pod
  labels:
    component:web
spec:
  containers:
    - name: client
      image: stephengrider/multi-worker
      ports:
        - containerPort: 9999
```

**client-node-port.yaml**

```
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: client-node-port
spec:
    type: NodePort
    ports:
        - port: 3050
          targetPort: 3000
          nodePort: 31515
    selector:
        component:web
```

I can see the status of both the pod and the service as running when I run the below commands:

```
> kubectl get pods

NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
client-pod                        1/1     Running   0          60m
```

```
> kubectl get services

NAME               TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
client-node-port   NodePort    10.99.14.107   <none>        3050:31515/TCP   63m
```

Then I found out the service url on the minikube cluster:

```
> minikube service list

|-------------|------------------|-----------------------------|
|  NAMESPACE  |       NAME       |             URL             |
|-------------|------------------|-----------------------------|
| default     | client-node-port | http://192.168.99.101:31515 |
| default     | hello-minikube   | http://192.168.99.101:31324 |
| default     | kubernetes       | No node port                |
| kube-system | kube-dns         | No node port                |
|-------------|------------------|-----------------------------|
```

I was able to access hello-minikube service with the URL mentioned against it in the table. But I could not access the client-node-port service and it just says:

```
This site can’t be reached192.168.99.101 refused to connect.
```

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Your service target port is `3000` while your container open port is `9999` where service is going to connect and send request.

Change the target port in service to `9999` and then test.Also check container is in running state.

Comment: I made my targetPort as 9999 which is the same as container port and redeployed the service. The issue still persists. :/

Answer (score 2):

> ContainerPort is used to decide which of the container's ports should be used by the service.
>
> The target port on svc spec specifies which port the service should hit when a request arrives.

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: client
      image: stephengrider/multi-worker
      ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
```

Since the `stephengrider/multi-worker` image you're using used `3000` as default port, set `containerPort` to `3000`. Update the pod yaml. It should work.

N.B: You should always target those ports from your service that are valid from pod's side.

Comment: I made my targetPort as 9999 which is the same as container port and redeployed the service. The issue still persists. :/

Comment: @MarcoPolo set both `targetPort` and  `containerPort` to `3000`. Guessing  you haven’t  get it from my ans.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issues. I deleted both node-port & pod configurations and re-deployed it. It worked.